# How to stop having to press enter upon --more-- using ssh in putty?

Tags: ssh, putty

How do I stop having to press enter upon  --more-- using ssh in putty?

Thanks, im new to SSH and Putty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go down a **page at a time** instead of a line at a time, press **space** instead of enter.

If you want to **quit** instead, just type **q**.